# Optaplanner - Traveling Sales man (vehicle routing) java client sample

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-vehicle-routing

I am trying to solve a routing problem. Ours is a simple process, multiple sales persons route needs to be scheduled prior.
Eg: sales person 1, visit locations A, B, C, D, Sales person 2  visit locations P, Q, R, S.

A nightly job will process and identify a better route for each person, like Sale person 1 – BADC, Sales person 2 – PQSR

Please help me in some kind of documentation or sample implementation. I am using Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out by going through the code.